# Preserve tree structure in Django model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-forms

I have a model with a parent field that refers to itself, like so:

````py
class Employee(models.Model):
     manager = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank = True )```
````

For the root node, this field will be blank.

When creating a new data instance, I want to make sure I do not add a data instance that ruins the implied tree structure. For instance, if two instances are parents of each-other, or there is some cycle.

Choices for the user will be presented via a form, so I need to restrict the choices that are presented to the user, doing something like:

```py
class EmployeeForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = CategoryModel
        
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Restrict choices so tree structure is not messed with
        self.fields['manager'].queryset = subset_parents()
```

How should subset_parents() be defined?

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand perfectly about what you want with users. However, if you want to create trees with your objects the best way to go is using the package [Django-mptt](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) where you have all the power to create objects with `parents`, `childs` and `nodes`. In addition inheriting its `MPTTModel` into your model, inheriting as a result fields to represent the location of such as the id of the tree and what is the parent object id the object is.

Implementation example:

```py
from django.db import models
from mptt.models import MPTTModel, TreeForeignKey

# Create your models here.
class TestTree(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    # Added after the creation of model, made - 
    # the migration and added data to the db.
    parent = TreeForeignKey(
        "self", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name="children"
    )
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # script to rebuild the tree in case it is not organized. # <-------
        super(TestTree, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            trees = TestTree.objects.all()
            for tree in trees:
                if tree.lft or tree.rght or tree.tree_id == 0:
                    TestTree.objects.rebuild()

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            pass
```

Example of creating a tree:

```py
records = MyModel.objects.build_tree_nodes({
    'id': 7,
    'name': 'parent',
    'children': [
        {
            'id': 8,
            'parent_id': 7,
            'name': 'child',
            'children': [
                {
                    'id': 9,
                    'parent_id': 8,
                    'name': 'grandchild',
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
})
```

For a must, [read this part](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/utilities.html) to increase your power to deal with trees using this package.